# How to navigate between different HTML pages using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I looked this problem up and tried an approach but couldn't get it to work.  I have a navbar that holds the titles of my pages:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav text-md-center nav-justified w-100">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Politics</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sports</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Business</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Health</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Technology</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Just to see if my approach was going to work, I made the following changes to one of the nav links (Politics):

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" onClick="clickInner(this);">Politics</a>
</li>
```

And added this in my JS file:

```
function clickInner(target) {
    location.href='../politics.html';
};
```

But the politics.html file does not launch when I click its corresponding nav link.  The HTML files are in the same level as the directory that holds the JS file.  Basically, I want the existing page to turn into the HTML that was clicked on as opposed to opening a new tab.

Comment: Set the href in the nav. A function is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a class="nav-link" href="politics.html">Politics</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using "../politics.html" the link redirects to the parent directory of the current folder and as you said the politics.html file is in the same level as the directory that holds the JS file, you should point the href to the current directory.

```
    function clickInner(target) {
      console.log(target);
      location.href = './politics.html';
    }
```

or you can simply use the href attribute of the  tag

```
    <a class="nav-link" href="./politics.html">Politics</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your target filename as a function param:

HTML :

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" onClick="clickInner('politics.html');">Politics</a>
</li>
```

Javascritp

```
function clickInner(target) {
    window.location.href= `./${target}`  ;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, `location.href` don't load a file, it change and redirect to a new url.

Knowing that you have some options:

1. Put all the url (http://mywebsite.com) on the `href`
2. Instead of change the `href` you can change the `pathname` to the name of your html file, but the all html you use should be on the root folder.
3. You could create a link element on js, put that href on the created link and trigger a click on it by js too.

But as @wazz said, the much better way to do this is just a normal `a` link to the file.